# Traducción de "Bold Move" al español

Tags: traducción, modismos

He querido buscar la traducción de esta frase al español, y me he encontrado con que el traductor de Google la traduce como "movimiento audaz", pero honestamente a mí no me parece una traducción correcta.

En sí porque creo que `audaz` es cuando algo se realiza con gallardía y destaca con maestría.

Sin embargo el "bold movement" no refleja esa maestría y habilidad, es más bien todo lo contrario: es un movimiento riesgoso pero que puede resultar efectivo.

Lo que más se me viene a la mente es "movimiento atrevido" y me parece mejor, sobre todo porque me parece que "fearless" es una mejor traducción para `audaz`.

Por su parte la palabra `bold` me refleja el significado de ser "directo", "claro" , "obvio" , "descarado" y no precisamente audaz.

Por su parte diría que `bold` es todo lo contrario a `audaz`.

El que es audaz transforma las maneras de resolver el problema.
El "bold" me parece que es terriblemente directo, o "atrevido".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta es la definición de `Bold` de acuerdo al [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bold)

> Fearless before danger / showing or requiring a fearless daring spirit
>
> Impudent, presumptuous

Es decir: que no muestra miedo ante el peligro, o hace gala de una espíritu o actitud que desafía al miedo o al peligro. El resto de acepciones son obsoletas, con el significado de "presuntuoso".

A mi la traducción que más me gusta para "bold" es "osado", que es por cierto usado en la [definición de "audaz" en el DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4MlGa9n). Osado es aquel me muestra atrevimiento o resolución.

Por supuesto hay más traducciones para `bold` (todas posiblemente sinónimos de osado).

La serie de televisión *Batman: the brave and the bold* fue traducida en título al español como "[Batman el Intrépido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Brave_and_the_Bold)". Intrépido, de acuerdo al DRAE es

> intrépido, da
>
> 1. adj. Que no teme en los peligros.
> 2. adj. Que obra o habla sin reflexión.

Que se asemeja más a la definición de `bold` del diccionario Merriam-WEbster.

Personalmente, yo sí habría osado "movimiento audaz" para "bold move", aunque reconozco es la connotación de `audaz` en esa expresión puede ser también de "astuto".

Otras, como "movimiento osado" pueden connotar "imprudente" o "falto de tacto o carisma" y "movimiento valiente" quizá sea demasiado plano.

Traducir como "movimiento intrépido" puede ser la opción más correcta, pero he de decir que no vende tan bien (no tiene el mismo valor expresivo) como "movimiento audaz". En le fondo traducir tiene también mucho de arte, y no solo de ciencia, y "audaz" sea la palabra en español que mejor transmita lo que "bold" quiere decir en "bold move", aunque haya términos que se asemejen más a la definición de "bold".

Comment: Me gusto mas "Movimiento Osado" principalmente por que "bold movement" por lo común quiere decir que rompe los esquemas de "lo normal" y en cierta medida es imprudente.  y principalmente siento que el catalogarlo como "imprudente, audaz, astuto, etc" es en base al resultado y no en base a la osadía de de cometer dicha acción. creo que de ese rompimiento de esquemas es por lo que la "explicación" y no la "traducción" se confunde con "audaz" que se basa mas en habilidades y estrategias

Answer (score 4):

**Jugada audaz**

Así se dice en el ajedrez y de ahí se puede usar en cualquier contexto... si eres audaz.

Comment: bien jugado... bien jugado...

Comment: This contribution appears in the "low quality" queue, probably due to length. Maybe you should expand a little bit more (Perhaps adding a reference? discussiong or comparing alternatives?) so this contribution stands out as an answer and not as a comment.

Comment: @Diego - Length judgments are made by stupid machines.  My answer is intended to be elegantly succinct, or to put it more boldly, it is intended to be bold.